# Is the use of a specific web browser engine relevant in a Cordova app?

Tags: css, cordova

I'm wondering if there's a difference between using WebKit and any other web browser engine in CSS for a Cordova app.

Does it differ like it would on a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The WebViews on different operating systems are different and have different levels of HTML/CSS support.

The iOS WebView is built on WebKit. The Android WebView used WebKit until Android 4.4 when it switched to Chromium. That's why you may see significant differences in css in Cordova apps between Android 4.3 and 4.4.